# .htaccess URL rewrite How to /file.php?type=v1 change to /v1/file.php

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I tried many ways from google but have no luck to do this, anyone please help me appreciated:
original 
    **/file.php?type=v1**,
public show as
    **/v1/file.php**

How to write in htaccess?

Comment: you can try something like : `RewriteRule ^(.+)/file.php$ /file.php?type=$1 [L,NC]` OR `RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+).php$ /$2.php?type=$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: Thanks bro, it is working!

Comment: @ravisachaniya If the url have dynamic query string how to add in? something like file.php?a=1&b=2

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: Cool this is what I looking for bro, million thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/file.php$ /file.php?type=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+).php$ /$2.php?type=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```